# proguard: my app doesn't build

Tags: java, android, proguard

Could You help me with build my app. I'm using elicpse, and when I try build my app I recived information with problem with proguard:

Please, help me with configure proguard-project.txt file

```
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Note: there were 3066 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-api-services-oauth2-v2-rev43-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-api-client-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-http-client-gson-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-oauth-client-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [gson-2.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-http-client-jackson2-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-http-client-jackson-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-api-client-android-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-http-client-jackson-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/pom.xml] (Duplicate zip entry [google-http-client-jackson-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/pom.xml])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/pom.properties] (Duplicate zip entry [google-http-client-jackson-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-jackson/pom.properties])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-api-services-drive-v2-rev90-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.xml] (Duplicate zip entry [protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.xml])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.properties] (Duplicate zip entry [protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.properties])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.xml] (Duplicate zip entry [protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.xml])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.properties] (Duplicate zip entry [protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/pom.properties])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.1.3.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/CheckForNull.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/CheckForNull.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/CheckForSigned.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/CheckForSigned.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/CheckReturnValue.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/CheckReturnValue.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/Detainted.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/Detainted.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/MatchesPattern.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/MatchesPattern.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/Nonnegative.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/Nonnegative.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/Nonnull.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/Nonnull.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/Nullable.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/Nullable.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/OverridingMethodsMustInvokeSuper.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/ParametersAreNonnullByDefault.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/ParametersAreNullableByDefault.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/PropertyKey.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/PropertyKey.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/RegEx.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/RegEx.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/Signed.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/Signed.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/Syntax.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/Syntax.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/Tainted.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/Tainted.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/Untainted.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/Untainted.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/WillClose.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/WillClose.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/WillCloseWhenClosed.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/WillCloseWhenClosed.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/WillNotClose.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/WillNotClose.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/concurrent/GuardedBy.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/concurrent/GuardedBy.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/concurrent/Immutable.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/concurrent/Immutable.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/concurrent/NotThreadSafe.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/concurrent/NotThreadSafe.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/concurrent/ThreadSafe.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/concurrent/ThreadSafe.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/meta/Exclusive.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/meta/Exclusive.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/meta/Exhaustive.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/meta/Exhaustive.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifier.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifier.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierDefault.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierDefault.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierNickname.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierNickname.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierValidator.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/meta/TypeQualifierValidator.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [javax/annotation/meta/When.java] (Duplicate zip entry [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/meta/When.java])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [google-api-services-drive-v2-rev90-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.google.apis.google-api-services-drive/pom.properties] (Duplicate zip entry [google-api-services-drive-v2-rev90-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.apis.google-api-services-drive/pom.properties])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/maven/com.google.apis.google-api-services-drive/pom.xml] (Duplicate zip entry [google-api-services-drive-v2-rev90-1.15.0-rc.jar:META-INF/maven/com.google.apis.google-api-services-drive/pom.xml])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/ASL2.0] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar:META-INF/ASL2.0])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar:META-INF/LICENSE])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar:META-INF/NOTICE])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [org/codehaus/jackson/impl/VERSION.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar:org/codehaus/jackson/impl/VERSION.txt])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.1.3.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Maciej\AppData\Local\Temp\android_8171337311121617932.jar] (Can't read [C:\AndroidApps\AppForMe\.google_apis\androidpublisher-v1.1r4lv1.15.0-rc\androidpublisher\libs\jackson-core-2.1.3.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.1.3.jar:com/fasterxml/jackson/core/base/GeneratorBase$1.class]))
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:264)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.OutputWriter.execute(OutputWriter.java:160)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.ProGuard.writeOutput(ProGuard.java:372)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:153)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [C:\AndroidApps\AppForMe\.google_apis\androidpublisher-v1.1r4lv1.15.0-rc\androidpublisher\libs\jackson-core-2.1.3.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.1.3.jar:com/fasterxml/jackson/core/base/GeneratorBase$1.class])
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:230)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.OutputWriter.writeOutput(OutputWriter.java:253)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  ... 4 more
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [jackson-core-2.1.3.jar:com/fasterxml/jackson/core/base/GeneratorBase$1.class]
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.io.JarWriter.getOutputStream(JarWriter.java:139)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:105)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryWriter.getOutputStream(FilteredDataEntryWriter.java:92)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.io.ClassRewriter.read(ClassRewriter.java:68)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:87)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:65)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.readFiles(DirectoryPump.java:65)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:53)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226)
[2013-08-15 13:50:54 - AppForMe]  ... 6 more
```

Now my proguard-project.txt file looks like this:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

-ignorewarnings
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.**
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontpreverify
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
```

I've tried different methods that I found on the internet, but unfortunately none of them could result. Please help, because this is already the mosque a few days and nothing: (